# Under which varna do bureaucrats come?

Tags: caste-system, varna, varnashrama

Do modern day bureaucrats come under the kshatriya varna? Any example related to this from shastras?

Comment: beurocrats comes under service sector. I think they are shudra

Comment: If possible, please list of the duties of bureaucrats under consideration. Then, it will be easy to answer.

Comment: Anyone doing any kind of job in Government or Private is called as a either a "Government Servant", or "Private Servant", and thus, from the Group D clerical Jobs to the Secretary Level highest bureaucrats, they'll will be termed Shudra as per their "current - jobs". Even the Judges of any court are basically under in a service to the Government and also get paid (for their services) - therefore, even the Judges ars under the "Shudra Varna".

Comment: By this "govt servant" logic even PM & President are just lowly shudras. No -- A govt servant is person in position of power responsible for admin. So he will be Kshatriya if he abides by rules and regulations of Hinduism for Kshatriyas..... Otherwise he will be Shudra or Chandala.

Comment: And by this awesome "power-Kshatriya" logic, everyone including the "clericals" is a Brahmin these days since they're involved in lots of scribing & reading/writing works.

Comment: All - all -questions about varna eventually have as their lowest common denominator have as their real question whether varna is determined by birth or by an individual's qualities.

Comment: @Vivikta by logic of govt servant thing, even people working in defence also will be included in shudras. I mainly asked about administrative department. IAS officers to be specific. What u think about it?

Comment: Yes everyone is basically a Shudra these days ( which is NOT a bad thing, as believed by many) - because we don't have a righteous "Kshtriya" King (in the scriptural sense of the Word) & also NO "Kingdom". Period.